# Downloading core via command-line

Tags: drush, 8

I usually download the latest Drupal 7 using `drush dl drupal --select`, but but Drupal 8 doesn't get listed.

What are some nice and quick ways of download the latest version of Drupal 8, even though it is still in alpha stage?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
drush dl drupal-8
```

Since there are no *stable* releases of Drupal 8, you must use the --all option to see the tagged alpha releases:

```
drush dl drupal-8 --select --all
```

This also works.

```
drush dl drupal --default-major=8 --select --all
```

Both of these are now working in the current version of Drush, without the `--all` flag:

- `drush dl drupal-8 --select`
- `drush dl --default-major=8 --select`

Note that the Drush pm-* commands only work with one major version of Drupal at a time, and that version currently defaults to Drupal 7. Therefore, `drush dl drupal` only shows the various Drupal 7 releases available, and does not include any versions of Drupal 8. This much has not changed.

`drush dl drupal-8` now works fine with the Drupal 8.0.0-rc1 release.

Comment: The version *now* currently defaults to Drupal 8. `drush dl drupal-7` works for latest stable Drupal 7 release.

Answer (score 4):

Since `drush dl` has been [deprecated](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/231741/1908) in recent Drush 9, so you need to use Composer in order to download Drupal 8 sources from the command line. E.g.

```
composer require drupal/drupal
```

<sup>Prefix with `sudo` to override the permissons (not recommended).</sup>

If you're in `/var/www/html` directory and you want to place your Drupal 8 sources there, you can run the following commands:

```
cd /var/www/html
sudo composer create-project drupal-composer/drupal-project:8.x-dev --no-interaction .
sudo ln -vs web/.* web/* .
```

Read about [differences between `drupal/drupal` and `drupal-composer/drupal-project` here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/186970/1908).

---

Alternatively download Drupal sources and extract them manually via:

`curl -s https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/drupal-8.2.7.tar.gz | tar --strip-components=1 -zxvf -`

<sup>Notes: Change the version to the latest one. Prefix `tar` with `sudo` if required.</sup>