# Is Drush abandoned?

Tags: 8, drush, composer

I installed Drush via Composer ([like the Drush site recommends](http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/)). Every time I run `drush dl drupal-7.x`, I get a message telling me that I should use Composer.

> [notice] dl has been deprecated. Please build your site using Composer. Add new projects with composer require drupal/[project-name]. Use https://www.drupal.org/project/composer_generate to build a composer.json which represents the the enabled modules on your site.

I downloaded Drupal 8 following these [instructions for installing Drupal via Composer](https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project), but when I run `drush dl devel` in that project I get this message.

> This codebase is assembled with Composer instead of Drush. Use `composer update` and `composer require` instead of `drush pm-updatecode` and `drush pm-download`. You may override this error by using the `--pm-force` option.

Is there something wrong with my local env, or is Drush a thing of the past now?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have installed the development `master` branch of Drush. To continue using commands such as `drush dl`, `drush pm-update` and so on, you should [install the 8.x branch of Drush](http://docs.drush.org/en/8.x/install/).

However, your basic supposition is correct. The Drupal community is moving towards Composer and away from `drush make` and the drush `pm-*` commands. The reason for this is that more and more Drupal modules are depending on code that is distributed via Composer libraries. When using modules with Composer dependencies, the most convenient way to manage your Drupal site is through Composer. See [drupal-composer/drupal-project](https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project) for an example of this.

All of the other Drush commands are still relevant and remain useful.

Comment: Ah, thank you.  There is still enough documentation by people using drush to manage D8 that it was very difficult to determine if composer was replacing drush or simply being used to install/manage drush.  Anyway, this quickly rolled me back to the drush I'm familiar with: `$ composer require drush/drush:8.x`